Need SelectListtem value that will match null value
If I set a nullable int to null in my page model.
[BindProperty]
public int? ProductId { get; set; }

ProductId = null;

How can I make it match one of my SelectListItem options?
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="ProductId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="ProductId" class="form-select" asp-items="Model.ProductOptions"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="ProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

I created ProductOptions with my list of products, including an empty option with Value set to "". But this empty option is not selected when the page is displayed.
If the user selects the empty option and submits the page, the value will show as null. Is there a way to create an empty option that will match my null value when the page loads?

One way would be to create a model and perform a small translation or mapping and bind ui to the model as 0 equals null.

@RossBush: Yes, I was hoping to avoid that. I'm using this logic in more than one place. If the page is submitted with the empty option selected, my ProductId will be null. I just want it to go the other way. Was hoping there was some way to make it not require special translation code (although I expect that's what I'll need to do if there is no other option).

I was not able to find a built-in way of handling this.
So what I did was add a property to my page model. This property gets or sets the value of ProductId but translates null to 0, and vice versa.
public int NonNullProductId
{
    get => ProductId ?? 0;
    set => ProductId = (value > 0) ? value : null;
}

And then used this value in my markup.
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="ProductId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="NonNullProductId" class="form-select" asp-items="Model.ProductOptions"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="NonNullProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

And then just set the value of my No Product option to 0.
